# How can I quickly show python help documentation from emacs without opening a Python shell?

Tags: python, emacs

As I code in emacs, manually launching python just to view the help information is cumbersome. I am lazy.

Is there a simple bash command to directly show python help without a pile of keystrokes?

I [answered my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72504328/2745495), but I am also hoping that someone will tell me how to do it straight from emacs.

Comment: I usally open another terminal window to run ipython~

Comment: You can use LSP to see function documents and signature automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating what ended up to be a simple function in .bashrc as follows:

```bash
manp() { # MODULE[.TOPIC] or TOPIC
   case $# in
      1) python3 <(cat <<EOF
try: import ${1%%.*}
except Exception: pass
help('$1')
EOF
                  ) ;;
      *) >&2 echo "manp MODULE[.TOPIC] or TOPIC"
         return 1
   esac
}
```

It seems to work fine.

```bash
manp print
```

Shows help on the print command. The import silently fails because there is no module named print.

```bash
manp argparse
```

Imports argparse and shows help on it (argument does not contain a dot).

```bash
manp argparse.Action
```

Imports argparse and shows help for the Action class.